# Would I have to apply the chain rule to this anti-derivative problem?

Tags: calculus

$$3t(t^3 + 1)$$

It looks like that I would have to apply the chain rule to this.

$$ (3t^2/2 )(t^4/4 + x) + c$$

This is what I got, but I'm sure if it's right because there is no way for me to check for the answer.

Comment: To check if your answer is correct, differentiate $3t^2/2 (t^4/4 + x) + c$. Do you get $3t(t^3 + 1)$?

Comment: If you are trying to find $\int 3t(t^3+1)\,dt$, it is very wrong. Multiply through by $3t$ and integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the chain rule is for derivative. Write
$$3t(t^3+1)=3t^4+3t$$
and rather use that the antiderivative is linear

Comment: Again, just right! +1